# Get max date from a nested array

Tags: php, arrays, date

If I have the following array how can I get the max expiry date? The expiry date is always the value in the values array with key 5 i.e.  `$results['values']['5']`

```
  array (
     0 => 
       array (
         'values' => 
            array (
              1 => '123456',
              2 => 'Blue',
              3 => 'Container',
              4 => '03-01-2020',  // start date
              5 => '03-01-2021',  // exp date
              6 => '',
              7 => '',
           ),
        ),
     1 => 
       array (
         'values' => 
            array (
              1 => '21312',
              2 => 'Green',
              3 => 'Box',
              4 => '2019-04-12',  // start date
              5 => '',            //exp date
              6 => '',
              7 => '',
            ),
         ),
     2 => 
       array (
         'values' => 
            array (
              1 => '434324',
              2 => 'Orange',
              3 => 'Box',
              4 => '2018-04-28', // start date
              5 => '2019-04-23', // exp date
              6 => '',
              7 => '',
            ),
      ),
  )
```

I know I can do something as follows for a simple array:

```
 $max = max(array_map('strtotime', $arr));
 echo date('d F Y', $max);
```

How can I achieve the same with a nested array?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you're already using `array_map`, you may use a custom function that grabs the expiry date and uses `strtotime` on it in one go:

```
$expiryDates = array_map(static function ($entry) {
  return strtotime($entry['values'][5]);
}, $input);

echo date('d F Y', max($expiryDates));
```

**Demo: https://3v4l.org/AiFtA**

Bonus - using PHP 7.4 short closures:

```
$expiryDates = array_map(fn($entry) => strtotime($entry['values'][5]), $input);
echo date('d F Y', max($expiryDates));
```